# how to show directory project view on left in gvim?

Tags: windows-7, gvim

I recall there is a plugin or such that I can use gvim on Windows to show me a leftside directory right in the vim pane, like a project view of the current directory.

For example, without a plugin I can type :n c:\ and it gives me the directory view but it fills the entire pane view. I just want it to the left while I work on a file.

Maybe you can think of a shortcut entry or any plugin that comes to mind?  I know I used it before, can't remember what I did or if it's a gvim thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is [NERDTree](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658) what you're looking for?

Comment: Maybe.  I see it already installed but :help NERD_tree.txt doesn't work.  How to evoke it?  :NERDtree fails (not a command)

Comment: trying F2 key and it seems to be already mapped to that key but it still says NERDtree not a command.  I'll try reinstalling it.  I'm running the :helptags ~/vimfiles/doc command

Comment: Try running the command `:NERDTreeToggle`.

Comment: ok, now I got the :help NERDtree txt file but every command says not and editor command :(

Comment: Hey that worked!  I can use it.  Thank you!  Cheers

Comment: Any way to fix the F2 mapping?  I have to use NERDTreeToggle and NERDTreeClose to use it

Comment: also can't :Bookmark or :ReadBookmarks ... seems many commands have missing mapping

Comment: anyway I'll go through the NERDTree docs and websites.  Thanks.